Finding references for Holder continuous measure valued paths.
I’m trying to find a reference about space of paths $\gamma \colon [0,T]\to M_{\alpha}$, where $M_{\alpha}$ is the space of measures where $W_{2}(\gamma_{s},\gamma_{t})\leq C|t-s|^{\alpha}$ for all $t,s\in [0,T]$.
Note that $W_{2}$ is the Wasserstein 2-metric.
I’m just curious about the general properties of these spaces. I looked around in Villani’s book, but I didn’t find anything. Any paper, lecture notes, textbook should be helpful.
Thanks!

Maybe there is something in
Ambrosio, Luigi; Gigli, Nicola; Savaré, Giuseppe (2005). Gradient flows in metric spaces and in the space of probability measures. Basel: Birkhäuser. doi: 10.1007/b137080
